# Flink 1.4.0 Kafka connector assign partition

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

In Kafka, you can assign the partitions using KafkaConsumer.assign:

```
KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(prop);
consumer.assign(partitions);
```

Is there a way to do the same for the FlinkKafkaConsumer010 or to get a handle on the KafkaConsumer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no. The kafkaFetcher field of FlinkKafkaConsumerBase (and its concrete children) is private. The KafkaConsumer itself is then further buried inside the fetcher.

With that said, I personally haven't found a situation where that held me back. Out of curiosity, why do you want access to the underlying consumer?

Comment: We have a custom kafka partitioner that assigns a message to certain flink instances given the payload of the message.  We figured it will be less messages that flink would have to filter if some of that work gets offloaded to the kafka producer side.